# using functions error (unresolved external) c++

Tags: visual-c++

what is the meaning of that error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPBS.png)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl checkprime(int)" (?checkprime@@YA_NH@Z) referenced in function _main   Project3    D:\projects\Project3\Source.obj

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Project3    D:\projects\Project3\Debug\Project3.exe 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You have declared a function named `checkprime` taking one parameter, and you are calling it, but you have never implemented it. You have implemented a different function, also named `checkprime` but taking two parameters; you aren't calling it.